# Cual es la mejor forma de iniciar un proyecto en python cuando estas aprendiendo

Tags: python

Hola Comunidad de Stack Overflow, especialmente la comunidad Python.

Como dice mi pregunta, soy principiante en Python, aunque ya llevo un conocimiento basico del mismo, pero me gustaria seguir aprendiendo y estoy abierta a sugerencias, consejos. Tengo planes de hacer proyectos poniendo en practica lo aprendido.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lamento comunicarte que no estas en el sitio adecuado. Tu pregunta es muuuy amplia. Nosotros ayudamos con temas concretos de programacion. Puedes buscar otro sitio o ganar reputacion aqui y hacer esa misma pregunta en el chat, donde sera mejor recibida c:

Comment: Tampoco damos opiniones en forma de respuestas. Suerte en tu busqueda!!!

Comment: Daré un voto positivo solo para vayas ganando reputación y puedas entrar al [chat] donde recibirás mucha más ayuda. Espero que @DanteS. También pueda ayudar a que alcances la reputación necesaria

Comment: @Christian hecho!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a los dos!!  @DanteS. y a Christian

Comment: De nada Yardiry, espero que te hayan respondido en el chat c: